# CakePHP 2.X - Set MySQL GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, group-concat

I found a nice way to retrieve quickly data I need using MySQL's `group_concat` awesomeness. However, I sometimes have long strings of data to retrieve. WHich should not be a problem if you just increase the `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` variable.

I am able to do so when testing my queries from the MySQL command-line interface. I am however unable to configure this properly from within CakePHP. I tried:

- adding `SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = <very_big_value>;` just before my query but this does not work.
- Modify CakePHP's `database.php` configuration file like so:

  ```
  class DATABASE_CONFIG {
      public $default = array(
          'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
          'persistent'    => false,
          'host'      => CONFUSEDBOY_DB_SERVER,
          'port'      => '',
          'login'     => CONFUSEDBOY_DB_USER,
          'password'  => CONFUSEDBOY_DB_PASSWORD,
          'database'  => CONFUSEDBOY_DB_NAME,
          'schema'    => '',
          'prefix'    => '',
          'encoding'  => '',
          'settings' =>array("GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN"=>"20000000")
         );
      [...]
  }
  ```

None of these things worked. Any idea how I can achieve what I want?

For information, I am using CakePHP 2.3 and MySQL 5.7.

**EDIT:** code showing how I tried to use `SET` just before the query (from a Model named `Things`)

```
<?php

/* This class represents things */
class Things extends AppModel {

    var $name   = 'Things';
    var $useTable = 'things';

    function getThingsWithGroupConcat($user_id) {
        $summary = array();  // Array that store results and is returned at the end
        $query = "SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=20000000;SELECT [...]  group_concat(foo) from things where user_id = '".$user_id."' [...];";
        $res = $this->query($query);
        for($i=0;$i< count($res);$i++){
             // Process query results to populate `$summary`
        }
        // pr($summary);
        return($summary);
    }


}
```

Comment: How did you use `SET` before the query? Could you add some example code to your question.

Comment: I modified my query string like so: `$query = "SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=20000000;SELECT [...]group_concat(foo) from confused_table where [...]";$res = $this->query($query);`. I will add further code to my question to give a bit more context.

Comment: You should really be only using `query()` to run the `SET` statement and then using a Cake `find()` for your select afterwards. I'm not sure how well `query()` would handle two statements like you are doing. I'd try separating them out and then checking which queries are being run by Cake using something like [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit).

Comment: Also, you should really be using singular names for your models, so in your example it would be `Thing`. You then don't need to specify the model's name and table in the model.